Highlighting Mismatch cells and sorting them at the top
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText= False
Dim lastRow As Long 
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Tiger, Lion, recon As Worksheet
Dim compareRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim dict As Object

Set recon= Thisworkbook.Workshets("Recon")
lastRow= recon.cells(recon.Rows.Count, "A"). End(xlup).Row
lastcol= recon.cells(1,recon.columns.Count).End(xlup).column

recon.sort.Sortfield.Clear

recon.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).NumberFormat ="@"
With recon.sort
.Sortfields.Clear
.SortField.Add2 Key: = Range("A2:A1401"_
), Sorton: = xlSortOnValues, Order: = xlAscending, DataOption" =_
xlSortTextAsNumbers
End With

With recon.Sort
.SetRange recon.Cells (1,1). CurrentRegion
.header= xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation= xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

Counter = 0
For i = 2 to LastRow
If recon.cells(i,1).Value = " " Then
recon. Range (recon.Cells (i,1), recon.Cells(i, lastcol)). Interior.Color - RGB(255, 182 193)
recon.cells(i,1).Value = "NO ID" + Str(counter)
counter = counter + 1
End If
Next i

Set compareRange = recon.Range("A1").Resize(lastrow,recon.Cells(1,          recon.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)'

For i =2 to LastRow

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(recon.Rows(i)) <> 0 Then

For j =2 to recon,cells(i,recon.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 2

If recon.cell(i,j).Value <> recon.cells(Application.Match(recon.cells(i,1).Value,    recon.Colums(1),0,j).Value Then

recon.cells(i,j).Interior.Color = RGB(255,182,193)
recon.cells(Application.Match (recon.cells(i,1).Value, recon.Columns(1),0), j).Interior.Color     =RGB(255,182,193)

End If
Next J
End If
Next i

 'Highlight entire row if single sided identifier
 For Each cell In recon.Range ("A2:A) & lastRow)
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(recib.Range("A2:A" 7 lastRow), cell.Value) = 1 Then
 Recon.Range(recon.Cells(cell.Row, 1), recon.Cells(cell.Row, lastcol)).Interior.Color =         RGB(255,182,193)
End If 
If cell.Value = "" Then
recon.Range(recon.Cells(cell.Row, 1), recon.Cells(cell.Row, lastcol)).Interior.Color =         RGB(255,182,193)
End If
Next Cell

Sheets("Recon").Select

Call sortcol

MsgBox "Recon Complete.", , "Tiger Recon"

End Sub

Sub sortcol()

Dim recon, Tiger As Worksheet
Dim Tigerlr,lionlr As Long
Dim lastcol, lastRow As Long 
Dim colName As String, foundCol As Range Long
Dim visiblerange, refrange As Range

Set recon = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recon")
Tigerlr = recon.Cells(recon.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = recon.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
lastRow = recon.Cells(recon.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Recon.Sort.SortField.Clear
targetColor = RGB(255, 182, 193)

'Add color sortkey
For col = 1 To lastcol
With recon.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key:=recon.Columns(Col), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, _
DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers)
.SortOnValue.Color = targetColor
End With
Next Col

'Perform sort
With recon.Sort
 .SetRange recon.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion
 .header = xlYes
 .MatchCase = False
 .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
 .SortMethod = xlPinYin
 .Apply
End With

End Sub

Sub clearRecon()
Dim recon As Worksheet
Set recon = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recon")
recon.Cells.Clear
recon.Cells.ClearContents
End Sub

I am trying to compare the details between 2 rows using the identifier ClearingID between 2 systems Tiger and Lion. If there is a difference, the cell will be highlighted in red RGB(255, 182 193) and sorted at the top. If there is only 1 entry in either system, the entire row will be highlighted.
However, the below code only seem to be picking up missing clearing ID or missing entry. Different data in cell will not be picked up, nor sorted on the top.

Without seeing the range you try processing it is difficult to help you, only looking to a piece of cod which does not do what you want... Then, lastcol= recon.cells(1,recon.columns.Count).End(xlup).column is wrong. To return correctly it should be lastcol= recon.cells(1, recon.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column.

Does your posted code compile?  It seems to have a few typos...   Eg: Sortfield.Clear

Hey, is using VBA a strict requirement here? If you have Microsoft 365, you may be able get what you want with FILTER, SORTBY and conditional formatting.

Hi @nkalvi, yes I strictly need to be using VBA requirements. Thanks for your help.

Hi @TimWilliams, noted. Sorry the long code seems to have some typo. I will re-edit it again. Thanks for the input. Cheers.

Hi @FaneDuru, i managed to send a picture of range that supposed to be sorted. I cannot seem to highlight the difference in col H. They are same trade ID but i cannot highlight and sort them above.

Why not creating an Excel formula, based on VLookup() or Match() or ... worksheet functions, put those results in a helper column and sort, according to the values inside that column?
